# Read data from an auto-downloaded file using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to read data from a local file. It works when the file is at the same folder as the html and js files.

However in my case, there is URL link, once I click it, a file will be auto-downloaded to the local Downloads folder. I want to store the data in a variable in JS file for further use. But since the front-end coding is not allowed to access the client local files, I'm just wondering is there any way around to read the download file? Or to fetch the data before it is downloaded?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why cant you [read the file](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) using the url?

Comment: Downloads don't occur in the window context. If it is an ajax download through your code you could work with the response. Or set server up to read the file perhaps